# Скачать Kotlin класс со storage firebase , и добавить его в проект

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase

Возникла задача - нужно хранить обычный класс **activity на сервере** , и когда человек проходил после splash screen , это класс скачивался , и переходил на нужное activity которое скачалось.

Как реализовать и с чем работать , куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Сделать так, как вы предложили - не получится. При добавлении нового класса все приложение придется перекомпилировать. Единственное решение - повесить OnClickListener на нужную кнопку для перехода на следующую Activity.

P.S. У Firebase есть хорошая [документация](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start#kotlin+ktx).

Comment: На самом деле можно скомпилированный класс скачать и использовать. С активити так, правда, не выйдет, т.к. его надо в манифесте прописать, но вот с фрагментом - получится. Однако это дыра в безопасности, засим гугл, например, такое приложение в магазин не пустит. И такую фичу следует использовать только если можно реально обосновать необходимость. Скорее всего задачу можно решить иначе, просто динамически отображая контент в зависимости от, например, информации из JSON пришедшего с сервера.

Comment: Хорошее предложение. С фрагментом так действительно получится, например в Android Studio есть [Apply Changes](https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes), которая применяет изменения кода  и ресурсов без перезагрузки приложения, а иногда и активити.

Comment: Если ответ решил вас вопрос, отметьте его принятым.